# SQL server store image and text on Datatype

Tags: sql-server

Can i store image and text on one data type (one column) in sql server. if yes, how can i retrieve based on content type image or text. i want use same column to store image or text (one at a time).

Comment: image and text are deprecated. Consider varbinary(max) or varchar(max). I would recommend just having two columns and simply using either one or the other as appropriate for the data. The empty one will take up only a tiny amount of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Varbinary Datatype to Store image as a byte datatype and it can use as a name

Answer (score 0):

If you encode your image to some plain text format this should work -- BASE64 maybe as a starting point. Encapsulating your data with some kind of start string and end string would allow your application to split them again later.

I would recommend **not** to do that. On most of DBMS there are special column types available for storing large binary data (I assume you are referring to jpg, png, bmp etc not svg).